# CSRF token mismatch Laravel Page Expired

Tags: php, css, reactjs, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a problem in the Production Environment in which this Exception is generated.
Check the Laravel authentication class and noticed that the session token was different from the token sent by the login form, all forms with CSRF, even so from the expired session. I've already optimized, cleared cache.

[Problem Page Expired at login time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGU6U.png)

[LocalHost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOuf3.png)

[Production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6gBy.png)

Comment: What about lifetime in config/session.php?

Comment: In `laravel.log` or into errors web server logs are there some permissions issues? Laravel version? Authentication type? Post more details please.

Comment: you could have a cookie problem, see if your sessions are working in general